# Fast way to create two list of certain pattern

Tags: python, list

I'd like to create two list (appearantly it doesnt need to be a list, can be tuple, array, numpy.array, see edit below) of a certain partern, lets call them list_1 and list_2

list_1 has the patern that can be described as (i is an integer)

{i}, {i, i + 17}, {i, i+17 , i + 17 + 17}, {i, i + 17, i + 17 + 17, i + 17 + 17 + 17},

But the pattern occurs twice, which means that the resulting list will look like

```
list_1 = [i, i, i + 17, i, i + 17 , i + 34, i, i + 17, i + 34, i + 51, 
          i, i, i + 17, i, i + 17 , i + 34, i, i + 17, i + 34, i + 51]
```

Currently I'm doing it as (with i = 2 in this example)

```
some_limit = 5    
list_1 = [17 * x + i for b in range(some_limit + 1) for x in range(b)]
list_1 += list_1
```

result

```
[2, 2, 19, 2, 19, 36, 2, 19, 36, 53, 2, 19, 36, 53, 70, 2, 2, 19, 2, 19, 36, 2, 19, 36, 53, 2, 19, 36, 53, 70]
```

When some_limit is a big number this takes time. Is there a faster way?

list_2 has a pattern that can be described as (j is an integer)

{j} {j+1, j+1}, {j+2, j+2, j+2}, {j+3, j+3, j+3, j+3}

This pattern also occours twice but with a shift which means that the resulting list will look like

```
list_2 = [j, j+1, j+1, j+2, j+2, j+2, j+3, j+3, j+3, j+3,
          j+shift, j+1+shift, j+1+shift, j+2+shift, j+2+shift, j+2+shift, j+3+shift, j+3+shift, j+3+shift, j+3+shift,
```

Currently I'm doing it as (with j = 0 in this example)

```
some_limit = 5
arithemic_list = [k for k in range(some_limit + 1)]
rows_index_temp = [item -1 + some_limit * j * 2 for item, count in zip(arithemic_list, arithemic_list) for k in range(count)]
rows_index_temp += [some_limit + elem for elem in rows_index_temp]
```

result

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

When some_limit is a big number this takes time. Is there a faster way?

**Edit**

This is used to create sparse matrices for the optimization package cvxopt. A matrix is built by providing elements with their row and column indicies. For example a 3x3 identity matrix is created by 3 lists, elements = [1,1,1], rows = [0, 1, 2] and columns = [0, 1, 2]. My matrix is very large which implies that the lists will be very large.

From the documentation

> cvxopt.spmatrix(x, I, J[, size[, tc ] ])
> I and J are sequences of integers (lists, tuples, array arrays, . . . ) or integer matrices (matrix objects with
> typecode 'i'), containing the row and column indices of the nonzero entries. The lengths of I and J must
> be equal. If they are matrices, they are treated as lists of indices stored in column-major order, i.e., as lists
> list(I), respectively, list(J)

https://readthedocs.org/projects/cvxopt/downloads/pdf/1.2.0/

**Example**
Lets say we would like to create the following matrix:

```
[ 1.00e+00     0         0         0         0    ]
[ 2.00e+00     0         0      3.00e+00     0    ]
[    0         0         0         0      4.00e+00]
```

We are only interested in the non-zero-elements and we can group them as

```
element   row   column    
   1       0       0    
   2       1       0
   3       1       3
   4       2       4
```

Thus, by having

```
elements = [1,2,3,4,0] 
rows = [0,1,1,2, 3]
columns = [0,0, 3, 4, 4]
print(spmatrix(elements, rows, columns))
[ 1.00e+00     0         0         0         0    ]
[ 2.00e+00     0         0      3.00e+00     0    ]
[    0         0         0         0      4.00e+00]
```

Notice that the order doesnt mather, as long as the element,row,column are grouped together. Thus this would be equivalent.

```
elements = [4,2,3,1] 
rows = [2,1,1,0]
columns = [4,0, 3,0]
print(spmatrix(elements, rows, columns))
[ 1.00e+00     0         0         0         0    ]
[ 2.00e+00     0         0      3.00e+00     0    ]
[    0         0         0         0      4.00e+00]
```

What am I trying to create? (some_limit = 3)

[image]

This is basically a concatination of two lower triangual matrix, with a constant shift between its elements. So how would we describe this matrix?
If we focus on the "upper" lower triangual part which contains -1:s.

We can group as

```
element   row   column    
   -1       0       2    
   -1       1       2
   -1       1       19
   -1       2       2
   -1       2       19
   -1       2       36
```

The "lower" triangular part with only 1:s can be grouped as

We can group as

```
element   row   column    
   1       3       2    
   1       4       2
   1       4       19
   1       5       2
   1       5       19
   1       5       36
```

Together this become

```
element   row   column    
  -1       0       2    
  -1       1       2
  -1       1       19
  -1       2       2
  -1       2       19
  -1       2       36       
   1       3       2    
   1       4       2
   1       4       19
   1       5       2
   1       5       19
   1       5       36
```

Or,

```
element   row   column    
  -1       0       2    
  -1       1       2
  -1       1       2 + 17
  -1       2       2
  -1       2       2 + 17
  -1       2       2 + 2*17       
   1       1 + 2   2    
   1       2 + 2   2
   1       2 + 2   2 + 17
   1       3 + 2   2
   1       3 + 2   2 + 17
   1       3 + 2   2 + 2*17
```

Since the order doesnt mather, as long as element, row, column is grouped togethere, there might be a "better" pattern which I havent consider.

The size of this matrix is directly correlated with the number of elements in the list describing the elements, rows, and columns. I wish to have some_limit >=4343 => the lenght of each of the list elements, rows, and columns will be
(4343*(4343 + 1)/2)*2 which explodes quite fast...

```
some_limit
4343
len(list_1)
18865992
#size_of_matrix
<34744x73831 sparse matrix, tc='d', nnz=75463969>
```

Comment: never do `list_1 += list_1`, use `.extend()`

Comment: seems you are calculating the past series every time, you should store the calculated result (ex: memoization)

Comment: What is *i* in the 1st comprehension?

Comment: Build the long list first and then create the desired list by slicing this list

Comment: i is an integer but unknown, in the range (0,30) @CristiFati

Comment: `i` seems `1` in the first case

Comment: i is actually 2 in the first case, and j is 0 in the second. I've made an edit @Epsi95

Comment: Ya sorry, didn't notice your answer. I think @Yanirmr solution sounds good, you create the long list.

Comment: You mean it takes a long time to generate the list for big *limit* values (greater than tenths of thousands for example). Do you need the whole list at once (meaning why not use generators instead)?

Comment: I need the full list at once @CristiFati

Comment: Can you explain again how your two lists relate to that matrix? Are they the matrix in "flattened" form, or two of those three input lists? Can you show a very small but complete example? And how big exactly will the actual lists/matrix be?

Comment: Ive made an update @tobias_k . I've also come to the realization that you may be on the right track with generator. Since the lengths of the list that will create the matrix gets LARGE. I could use a generator as you suggested and create the matrix row by row and then concatenate the rows to create the full matrix

Comment: So the question might be reformulated, how can i create a generator which generates each row of the matrix... @tobias_k

Comment: But in the end you still need the entire matrix, so using a generator might not do you much good... I'll have another look at this later.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your list comprehensions to generator expressions, then you do not have to create the entire list at once but can generate values as needed. In particular note the additional loop I added so that you do not have to create the entire list, then add a copy to itself.

```
i, j, limit, shift = 2, 0, 5, 10

gen_1 = (17 * x + i for _ in range(2)      # repeat twice
                    for b in range(limit)  # len of subsegments
                    for x in range(b+1))   # multiplier

gen_2 = (j + b + s for s in (0, 10)        # repeat with shift
                   for b in range(limit)   # len of subsegments
                   for _ in range(b+1))    # repeat b times
```

You can then either iterate the values as needed (or still create a list from all the values):

```
for x in gen_1:
    print(x)
print(list(gen_2))
```

Comment: I did a timeit and this suggestion is not faster according to my testing

Comment: def f1():
    cols_index_temp = [17 * x + 2 for b in range(4500 + 1) for x in range(b)]
    cols_index_temp += cols_index_temp
    return cols_index_temp

Comment: timeit.repeat("f1()", "from __main__ import f1",
                  number=10)
[12.739764500001911, 12.630870299995877, 12.717473900003824]

Comment: def f2():
    gen_1 = (17 * x + 2 for _ in range(2)  
             for b in range(4500) 
             for x in range(b + 1)) 
    return list(gen_1)

Comment: timeit.repeat("f2()", "from __main__ import f2",
                  number=10)
[25.243890799989458, 24.826472699991427, 26.076174499990884]

Comment: @Olba12 Well, you still have to generate all the values. The point here is just that you can start working on the first values before creating _all_ the values, and you do not have to store everything in memory. There might be other ways to make it faster, but those might not work in all cases either. Maybe you should extend your question with that you actually need this for.

Comment: I've updated my question regarding what I need this for. And youre correct, this would be better for memory. Maybe that can be useful